# If $0.2349$ is approximated to $0.2299$, what is number of significant figures in such approximation?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, floating-point

> **If $0.2349$ is approximated to $0.2299$, what is number of significant figures in such approximation?**

Let $x_T=0.2349$, $x_A=0.2299$, then absolute error = $|x_T-x_A|=0.0050=\frac{1}{2}\times 10^{-2}=0.05\times 10^{-1}<\frac{1}{2}\times 10^{-1}$. Therefore, $x_A$ is correct upto 1 decimal place i.e., $x_A$ is correct upto $1$ significant place.

Note that the absolute error = $|x_T-x_A|=0.0050<\frac{1}{2}\times 10^{-1}$ is considered. If, instead, I take absolute error = $|x_T-x_A|=0.0050=\frac{1}{2}\times 10^{-2}$ and then if I conclude $x_A$ is correct upto $2$ decimal place i.e upto $2$ significant places then is it erroneous?

Comment: Please answer at the earliest convenience.

Comment: What is your definition of "significant figures"?